# How to move first row from Sheet1 to Sheet2, move second row on Sheet1 to Sheet3, move third row on Sheet1 to Sheet4 then repeat?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of data about 20k rows long and all data is in the first column. Each record has three rows of unique data.

I'm trying to move each row to a new sheet and repeat until the end of the workbook.

EX: Move first row from Sheet1 to Sheet2, move second row on Sheet1 to Sheet3, move third row on Sheet1 to Sheet4.

I've tired some variations of offset and index formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic formula will be:

```
=INDEX(A:A,(ROW(1:1)-1)*3+1)
```

Where the `*3` is the number of rows of unique data and the `+1` is the start row.  So on the first sheet it will be `+1`, `+2` for the next sheet and so on.

Copy over and down each sheet.

Comment: Thanks Scott, That works good down to row 25 on sheet1 then something happens and i start getting data from the 2nd record. This is the last formula that works =INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,(ROW(9:9)-1)*3+1) the formula that does pulls in the second record is =INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,(ROW(10:10)-1)*3+1) I'm not sure why it wont continue to work.

Comment: Then your data does not follow the pattern.

Comment: Look at rows 26 and 27 and you will see that data set only has 2 lines.

Comment: My apologies, You are correct...the records where similar but not the same. I'm noticing that the data has some outliers with 4 records instead of 3. I do appreciate your time and sorry for the confusion on my part.